# Getting the decimal variations on a number

Tags: c#, winforms, t-sql, data-conversion, negative-number

So, I have a number in a box, it can either be positive or negative. Depending on that choice, my algorithm changes.

Say I get 207 in the box, and it runs through my code block, I want to get every possible decimal variation of 207 from the database, though I might as well look through the others. So what I do is get numbers greater than 207 but less than one number above it, it looks something like this:

```
String DecimalValue = FilterUSD.Text.ToString().Trim();
Double Deci = Convert.ToDouble(DecimalValue);
Double init = Deci;
Double init2 = init + 1;
```

This gives me 207.50, 207.99, 207.13, etc. from the backend.

I need this for an SQL statement later on, but this is the important part:

```
sbuilder.Append(" Amount_USD").Append(" >= ").Append("@init AND Amount_USD < @init2 ");
```

When the sbuilder ( string builder ) is resolved, it looks something like this:

```
Select * FROM Table WHERE Amount_USD >= @init AND Amount_USD < @init2
```

This works as I expect it to and I get every decimal number of a given number, including that number.

What I need help with is the negative variation. I'm not certain what I'm doing wrong, but the juxtaposition of the code doesn't work, when I attempt to filter it through the SQL command, it would return no rows whatsoever.

Here's the full code:

```
String DecimalValue = FilterUSD.Text.ToString().Trim();
Double Deci = Convert.ToDouble(DecimalValue);
if(Deci < 0)
{
    //Negative
    Double init = Deci;
    Double init2 = init - 1;
    sbuilder.Append(" Amount_USD").Append(" <= ").Append("@init AND Amount_USD > @init2 ");
}
else
{
    //Positive, as above
}
```

SQL output of the code for negative bases:

```
Select * FROM Table WHERE Amount_USD <= @init AND Amount_USD > @init2
```

Comment: where do you add `init` and `init2` as parameters, and what are their values at the time they are added?

Comment: Ah, well they're int data types and init is equal to the base given number, and init2 is equal to the base +/- 1 depending on whether the base is negative or not.

Comment: Run the sql in management studio,first without the where clause. Then add in the first part of the clause run it again and look at the results. You should then be able to figure out (based on the data returned) how to formulate the last bit of it.

Comment: "Ah, well they're int data type" - in the now edited question, they are doubles, not integers... you aren't doing any range rounding that I can see... but again: the real trick here is to find *where you add the parameters*, and see what values you're adding at that point.

Comment: are you sure that those values exist in the database that match the condition? have you tried your second query in SQL Management Studio or LinqPad ?

Comment: My mistake, I copied it wrong, the value comes from a class in my code but I had to remove it cause it isn't relevant here. I updated the OP to reflect it. @MarcGravell Correct types are Double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we consider:

```
if(Deci < 0)
{
    //Negative
    Double init = Deci;
    Double init2 = init - 1;
    sbuilder.Append(" Amount_USD").Append(" <= ").Append("@init AND Amount_USD > @init2 ");
}
```

The values of `init` and `init2` here are **irrelevant** - they aren't used anywhere, and they certainly aren't the values used in the parameters. Instead, **find where you add the parameters**, and see what values you are adding **there**. I expect you're using the "+1" version, which would give an impossible range test.

A good approach here would be to declare the variables **outside** the `if` test, populate them *inside*, and then use the values afterwards; for example:

```
double init, init2;
if(Deci < 0) {
    init = Deci;
    init2 = init - 1;
    sqlBuilder.Append(" Amount_USD <= @init AND Amount_USD > @init2 ");
} else {
    init = Deci;
    init2 = init + 1;
    sqlBuilder.Append(" Amount_USD >= @init AND Amount_USD < @init2 ");
}
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@init", init);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@init2", init2);
```

This will *force you* to assign a meaningful value to the locals (`init`, `init2`) in both code paths.

Side note: you might want `decimal` instead of `double`; money is usually not floating point.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, you're right! I checked where I added the parameters into my command and it would seem I only used the block for positive in it. I'll sort this out. Surprised you could tell when I didn't even have the parameters block posted!

Comment: @Arvayne which is why I asked for that code :) but: what I *can* tell from your code is that `init` and `init2` **weren't ever used for anything**, which fuelled my hunch.

Comment: As an aside, could you not use ROUND for this - for both positive and negative numbers? e.g. ROUND(@init1,0,1) = @init2. Not got SQL Server installed so can't check.